# why can't using comparision operator directly in select statement in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

for the sql statements below,

1. select 1 + null from dual;
2. select 1 > null from dual;

why statement 1 is accepted but 2 has error in Oracle?

Comment: `1 > something` would evaluate to `true` or `false` (or in your specific example, `null`), and Oracle SQL doesn't have a boolean data type - at least not until [23c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/Changes-in-This-Release-for-Oracle-Database-SQL-Language-Reference.html#GUID-3C11D3A9-8B14-4DCC-B212-B7FE57EE81E8).

Comment: What output do you expect to see?